# Coin in rectangle

Tags: probability

A rectangle $m \times n$ is split into $N$ equal smaller rectangles of sides $m_1 \times n_1$.
We randomly drop a coin of radius $r < m_1 \leq n_1$. Find the probability that the coin completely fits in one of the small rectangles.

Area of each smaller rectangle is obviously $m_1 n_1$ and area of coin surface is $\pi r^2$. I don't know how to calculate the probability that it fits completely in one small rectangle!

Comment: To lie completely inside an $m_1\times n_1$ rectangle, the coin centre must happen lo lie in a smaller rectangle of size $(m_1-2r)\times (n_1-2r)$

Comment: This question is a duplicate, though I don’t know where on this site the first is.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/144766) tutorial.

Comment: Must the randomly dropped coin land entirely within the $m\times n$ rectangle?  Must its *center* land within it?  Must *some portion* of the coin land in the big rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

Some parameters seem unspecified in the question.  For example, how is the coin randomly thrown into the big rectangle.  I'll make some assumptions.

1. That the coin ends up flat on the rectangle
2. That the location of its center has a uniform distribution among all locations it can take.
3. That both $m_1$ and $n_1$ are greater than $r$.  Otherwise it is impossible for the coin to lie in the interior. (P=0)
4. That the coin cannot spill partly over the edge of the big rectangle.  So the center must be at least r from all edges.  So the center must lie within a rectangle of size $(m - 2r) \times (n-2r)$.

The coin is entirely within a small square if the center is within an even smaller rectangle of size $(m_1 - 2r) \times (n_1-2r)$ and there are N of these.  Since the distribution is assumed uniform, the probability you are looking for is $$P=\frac{N (m_1 - 2r) \times (n_1-2r)}{(m - 2r) \times (n-2r)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's first solve the trivial case: if $n_1 < 2r$ or $m_1 < 2r$, then the probability must be $0$.

If the center of the coin drop within the rectangle of length $n_1-2r$ and width of $n_2-2r$, then we are sure the coin will be in the rectangle of $m_1 \times n_2$. So the probability will be $$ \frac{(m_1-2r)( n_1-2r)}{m_1 \cdot n_1}$$